# Chrome.storage.sync.get() seems to be duplicating keys?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am saving some settings using the following sequence

```
var getSettings = async function() {

    var settings;
    try {
        settings = await authenticatedGET(server_url + SETTINGS_ENDPOINT);
        return settings;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Settings Fetch Failed: " + error);
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}

const setLocalSettings = function(settings) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'LML_Settings': JSON.parse(settings) }, function() {
        console.log("Settings saved locally");
    });
}
```

At the line right after the `setLocalSettings` function definition, the 'settings' object logs out as
`{"email_format":"individual","close_tab":true,"frequency":"DAILY"}` (correctly as intended).  When I go to fetch the settings using this sequence:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('LML_Settings', function(LMLSettingsContainer) {
                console.log(LMLSettingsContainer);
                if (LMLSettingsContainer.LML_settings.close_tab == "true") {
                    closeCurrentTab();
                }
            })
```

`LMLSettingsContainer` logs out as

```
{
  "LML_Settings": {
    "close_tab": true,
    "email_format": "individual",
    "frequency": "DAILY"
  }
}
```

accessing my settings with `LMLSettingsContainer.LML_Settings["<setting>"]` is a bit annoying (and its the whole reason I named the top variable LMLSettingsContainer).

Does anyone know if there's a way to have chrome save/get these values unwrapped?

Comment: `chrome.storage.sync.get('LML_Settings', ({LML_settings}) => { ... })`

Comment: Perfect,  thanks! Can you reply as an answer so I can Accept?

Answer (score 0):

chrome.storage.sync.get('LML_Settings', ({LML_settings}) => { ... }) works, per @wOxxOm